# Import Excel sheet into 3D array?

Tags: import, graphics3d, sparse-arrays

I have an excel spreadsheet that I would like to plot in a 3D graph using mathematica.  The X and Y values are the location of the cell, and the Z value is the number of the scale.

How can I import this into mathematica for plotting purposes?

Here is what my data looks like.
[image]

Comment: You can factor your Q into two parts: (1) data = Import["myFile.xls"] (if the file contains only a single worksheet, otherwise take parts). (2) Then you can transform this data to Graphics3D in a variety of ways.

Comment: @alancalvitti that worked... if you add it as an answer I will select it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Flatten[MapIndexed[{Sequence @@ #2, #1} &, 
                Import["ExampleData/elements.xls"] [[1]], {2}], 1] // TableForm
```

Requested explanation:

```
Import["ExampleData/elements.xls"][[1]]
```

Gets the first sheet in the file

```
MapIndexed[{Sequence @@ #2, #1} &, ...... , {2}]
```

Generates tuples of the form `{posx, posy, cellValue}`

```
Flatten[........, 1]
```

Gets rid of extra nesting levels on the resulting list

```
// TableForm
```

Formats the output you see below

[image]

Comment: This works great.  Thank you.  Do you think you could explain what it is doing, please?