# Creating ordered triplets from an Excel sheet

Tags: list-manipulation, import, formatting, excel

I have an Excel sheet of the form:

```
    " "  a  b  c
     1   R  S  T
     2   U  V  W
     3   X  Y  Z
```

Where every entry is a number (except the blank quotes, which is just a blank cell). These are supposed to be `{x,y,z}` coords but Mathematica imports them as `{" ",a,b,c},{1,R,S,T},...`. I get that I need to transpose them but I'm not sure how. Essentially for this example the end result should be `{a,1,R},{b,1,S},{c,1,T},{a,2,U}...`.

This is similar but without the extra lines which is kind of the issue I'm having: [Import Excel sheet into 3D array?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18460/import-excel-sheet-into-3d-array)

Comment: Are all of the cell entries strings?

Comment: No. I mentioned right after the example sheet that everything is a number (a float specifically)

Comment: Thanks.  What about a, b, c? Are they "a", "b", "c" or something else?

Comment: Those too. Everything that isn't the little blank space in the corner is a number. I just used the letters to make it easier to keep track of when I rearranged them. There are no strings anywhere (except for that blank space, which needs to get ignored).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
s = {{" ", a, b, c},
   {1, R, S, T},
   {2, U, V, W},
   {3, X, Y, Z}};
```

Traverse the rows and extract the triplets.

```
Table[{s[[1, j]], s[[i, 1]], s[[i, j]]},
  {i, 2, Length[s]}, {j, 2, Length[First@s]}] // Flatten[#, 1] &

(* {{a, 1, R}, {b, 1, S}, {c, 1, T}, {a, 2, U}, {b, 2, V}, {c, 2, W}, *)
(*  {a, 3, X}, {b, 3, Y}, {c, 3, Z}} *)
```

Comment: Very nice and straight forward!

Answer (score 0):

If the characters are loaded in as strings, then this works:

```
{M[[1, #2]], M[[#1, 1]], M[[##]]} & @@@ Select[Position[M, _String], #[[1]] != 1 &]
```

where `M` is the matrix. But, if the characters are symbols, then a little different processing is required

```
{M[[1, #2]], M[[#1, 1]], M[[##]]} & @@@ Select[
 Position[M, _Symbol, Heads -> False], #[[1]] != 1 &]
```

Note, that I had to add the option `Heads -> False` to  `Position`, otherwise it would capture `List`, also.

**Edit**: as it appears I misread the post, and `R`, etc. are numeric, this is simple to accomplish, also.

```
{M[[1, #2]], M[[#1, 1]], M[[##]]} & @@@ Select[
 Position[M, _?NumericQ], #[[2]] != 1 &]
```

All return

```
{{a, 1, R}, {b, 1, S}, {c, 1, T}, 
 {a, 2, U}, {b, 2, V}, {c, 2, W}, 
 {a, 3, X}, {b, 3, Y}, {c, 3, Z}}
```

with substitutions as appropriate.

Comment: Not quite. When I put it in (using numbers in Mathematica but for consistency substituting letters here).
`code`{{a,1,R},{a,2,S},{a,3,T},
`code` {b,1,U},{b,2,V},{b,3,W},
`code` {c,1,X},{c,2,Y},{c,3,Z}}

Comment: Double posting for clarity's sake since I couldn't get the mini-markdown down in the 5 minutes they gave me:
`{{a,1,R},{a,2,S},{a,3,T},  
 {b,1,U},{b,2,V},{b,3,W},  
 {c,1,X},{c,2,Y},{c,3,Z}}`

Comment: @Kyle I changed it on my machine, but didn't fix the bug on the code I posted. Fixed, now.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another idea.

```
rawData = {{" ", "a", "b", "c"}, {1, "R", "S", "T"}, {2, "U", "V", "W"}, {3, "X", "Y", "Z"}}
```

Separate the data from the spreadsheet headers

```
data = Rest[rawData] /. {_?NumberQ, tail__} :> {tail}
colHeaders = Rest@rawData[[1]]
rowHeaders = Rest@Transpose[rawData][[1]]
```

> {{"R", "S", "T"}, {"U", "V", "W"}, {"X", "Y", "Z"}}
>   {"a", "b", "c"}
>   {1, 2, 3}

Replace the information as required.

```
Most[ArrayRules[data]] /. ({c_, r_} -> d_) :> {colHeaders[[r]], rowHeaders[[c]], d}
```

> {{"a", 1, "R"}, {"b", 1, "S"}, {"c", 1, "T"}, {"a", 2, "U"}, {"b", 2, 
>     "V"}, {"c", 2, "W"}, {"a", 3, "X"}, {"b", 3, "Y"}, {"c", 3, "Z"}}

Comment: Same problem as rcollyer's. The end result is supposed to be:
`{a,1,R},{b,1,S},{c,1,T},{a,2,U}...`
BUT
Swapping a and b in your last line such that
`Most[ArrayRules[data]] /. ({a_, b_} -> d_) :> {colHeaders[[b]], rowHeaders[[a]], d}`
Does work! Thanks!

Make that change and I'll mark it accepted.

Comment: @Kyle as I've said to many new users, I recommend waiting 24 hours before you Accept an answer to give everyone a chance to read and respond.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks for the advice.

As it turns out, I spoke too soon anyway. This code ignores any point that has a 0 as one of the coords.

Comment: I meant if any of those symbols corresponds to a 0 (as in a,b,c,1,2,3,R,S,T,U), it will ignore all points in that column/row. So if a was 0, then any point that included a would be ignored.

Comment: Kyle.  I corrected the order of indices issue. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

This is not likely to be highly efficient, but I think it is pretty easy to follow, assuming you are familiar with *Mathematica* pattern and `Part` syntax:

```
in = {{" ","a","b","c"}, {1,"R","S","T"}, {2,"U","V","W"}, {3,"X","Y","Z"}};

f[x_][n_, {r_, c_}] := {x[[1, c]], x[[r, 1]], n}

Join @@ MapIndexed[f[in], in, {2}][[2 ;;, 2 ;;]]
```

> ```
> {{"a", 1, "R"}, {"b", 1, "S"}, {"c", 1, "T"}, {"a", 2, "U"}, {"b", 2, "V"},
>  {"c", 2, "W"}, {"a", 3, "X"}, {"b", 3, "Y"}, {"c", 3, "Z"}}
> ```

Or as a one-liner:

```
Join @@ MapIndexed[{in[[1, #2[[2]]]], in[[#2[[1]], 1]], #} &, in, {2}][[2 ;;, 2 ;;]]
```

Comment: As far as I can tell both the expanded and the one-liner work. Just ran it on the test set and then on my actual data and both times it looks right. Everything in the right place and nothing missing.

Comment: @Kyle Great. :-)  Let me know if you need an explanation of the code.  The basic idea is to use the coordinates of each element, provided by `MapIndexed`, to then extract the matching column and row headers.  This is basically what the other answers do too, but I think my way is cleaner.  If you are not familiar with function definitions of the form `f[x_][n_, {r_, c_}] := ` the one-liner may be easier to understand; they do the same thing.  (Regarding the definition you may read [(1)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8399/121) and [(2)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8003/121))

Answer (score 0):

For fun

```
data = {{" ", "a", "b", "c"}, {1, "R", "S", "T"}, {2, "U", "V", 
   "W"}, {3, "X", "Y", "Z"}}
data2 = {{" ", "COLLUMN1", "COLLUMN2", "COLLUMN3"}, {"ROW1", "R", "S",
    "T"}, {"ROW2" , "U", "V", "W"}, {"ROW3", "X", "Y", "Z"}}


f[data_] := Module[{cheader, rheader, rheaderlenght},
  cheader = data[[1, 2 ;; All]];
  rheader = data[[2 ;; All, 1]];
  rheaderlenght = rheader // Length;
  Flatten[
   Transpose[{ cheader, PadLeft[{}, rheaderlenght, rheader[[#]]],
       data[[1 + #, 2 ;; All]]}] & /@ Range[rheaderlenght], 1]
  ]
```

f[data] and f[data2] gives:

{{"a", 1, "R"}, {"b", 1, "S"}, {"c", 1, "T"}, {"a", 2, "U"}, {"b", 2, 
  "V"}, {"c", 2, "W"}, {"a", 3, "X"}, {"b", 3, "Y"}, {"c", 3, "Z"}}

and

{{"COLLUMN1", "ROW1", "R"}, {"COLLUMN2", "ROW1", "S"}, {"COLLUMN3", 
  "ROW1", "T"}, {"COLLUMN1", "ROW2", "U"}, {"COLLUMN2", "ROW2", 
  "V"}, {"COLLUMN3", "ROW2", "W"}, {"COLLUMN1", "ROW3", 
  "X"}, {"COLLUMN2", "ROW3", "Y"}, {"COLLUMN3", "ROW3", "Z"}}